# Need Arbitrary-Precision-Arithmetic in C#

Tags: c#, decimal, math, arbitrary-precision

I'm in need of floating point calculations for C# that can correctly store up to maybe 500 digits/decimals. Is there any built-in-type for this, do I have to create it myself, any library available or what is the best way to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MPIR](http://www.mpir.org/), a fork of the GMP project, has C# bindings. Personally, I've found them easier to deal with when raising problems, to the point that I no longer worry about GMP (primarily due to its tendency to exit violently when running out of memory).

There are others listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic) but I have no direct experience with them so can't comment on their usefulness.

Comment: There is also an implementation within Microsoft's J# redistributable (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=f72c74b3-ed0e-4af8-ae63-2f0e42501be1&displaylang=en). It's under the java.math namespace (you have to include vjslib.dll in your project). Unfortunately, Microsoft no longer officially supports J#, so this should be considered a 3rd party library.

Comment: Is the C# binding you're referring to X-MPIR?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that is more liberally licensed than MPIR is the BigInteger class available in the source code for the [Bouncycastle C# library](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/).