# select the right type of variable C#

Tags: c#, string, variables, math, pi

i want to create pi more than 16 thousand numbers after the decimal point
but the problam is that i kant find any type that could fill my wishes.
I tried to use object but it rounds the number after 10 
I thought using string but string type wont be able to do minus or plus and if i will
convert to int it will become round.
do you know any other types i can use or how can i make it work with a string
for example
http://files.extremeoverclocking.com/file.php?f=36 this program is able to calculate up to 32 million

thnx

Comment: Perhaps try a [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282727/how-can-i-use-a-very-large-string-500-million-characters-in-my-program)

Comment: What you're looking for would be called, in more technical language, an arbitrary precision decimal (or arbitrary precision float). I don't have any personal experience with them, but you could try the answers from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116078/need-arbitrary-precision-arithmetic-in-c-sharp) question?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176775/big-integers-in-c-sharp

Comment: @OnoSendai - Not really, since that's about integers and this is about decimals.  They're certainly similar in concept, though.

Comment: @Bobson, you're completely right; thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Download Microsoft solver foundation. Use the Rational type.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.boyet.com/Articles/PiCalculator.html) and it's `BigNumber` class.

> The first thing to note is that we can't use any of the primitive types in C#: they just don't have enough precision (the double type, for example, only has 15 significant digits, and we want to calculate, say, 10000). We need a large precision number library, but there's nothing like that in the .NET Framework, and so the first thing we'll have to do is write a BigNumber class.

That page also provides an example usage for calculating *pi* out to 1000 decimal places, so it should be fairly trivial to run it for 16000.

---

Running it for 16000 digits takes me about a second and a half, for 160,000 digits takes me a bit over 2 minutes.

Here's my `PrintAsTable()` function, which the linked post leaves as an exercise for the reader:

```
public string PrintAsTable() {
    var data = Print();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == '.') sb.AppendLine(".");
        else if ((i -1) % 50 == 0) sb.AppendLine(data[i].ToString());
        else if ((i -1) % 10 == 0) {sb.Append(data[i].ToString()); sb.Append(" ");}
        else sb.Append(data[i].ToString());
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```